# How can I create dynamically a static link for a Django template

Tags: python, html, django

I create dynamically images in the folder:

```
static/images/name_of_file.jpg
```

The name of the file is the value of ***img***.
I want to create dynamically a static link for a Django template in the view:

```
img="images/"+img+".jpg"
img="{% static \""+img+ "\" %}"
```

But it is not functioning. Any help in this direction?

Comment: send `img` in the context, and then `{{STATIC_URL}}{{img}}`

Comment: most of the images are online links; when I can not find an image (it happens rare), I create dynamically an image with text in it. The expression in the template is "<img src={{j}}", so I want the same expression to be used for both cases

Comment: Oh.. in the view, `"/".join(settings.STATIC_URL, "images/" + img + ".jpg")` ?

Comment: It says:"NameError: global name 'settings' is not defined"

Comment: you need to import - `from django.conf import settings`

Comment: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting STATIC_URL, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: just google that.. There is lots of help available.

Comment: you already helped a lot @kartkikr, I can continue now

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @karthikr, I solved the problem in this way:

```
from django.core.management import setup_environ
from mysite import settings

img="images/"+img+".jpg"
img=settings.STATIC_URL+img
```